# struts2 displays Radio button in a text view

Tags: java, struts2

Am retrieving the gender from the list and displaying in a jsp page.It is displaying the values I stored in the list but not the Radio button. any help will be appreciated

```
<s:radio list="genderList" value="Gender" label="Gender"
                                  name="accountBean.gender"></s:radio>
```

**DAO:**

```
public ArrayList<String> getGender() {

    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();    
    list.add("Male");
    list.add("Female");
    return list;            
}
```

The **output** which am getting is:

Gender

Male Female

**Expected output:**

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: `getGender` != `genderList`.

Comment: @AleksandrM It is displaying the rsult when I called it from my action class but the Radio button doesnt appear. In my action class using the genderList object am calling the DAO method.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Your code is correct but make an array list named "genderList" and its getter/setter in your Action Class it will work fine.

Comment: Am having getters and setters for my array list named "genderList". thats why I got the result in my jsp page but the problem is the radio button doesnt appear for those list

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
<s:radio list="genderList" value="Gender" label="Gender"
                              name="accountBean.gender"></s:radio>
```

Action class :

```
package mypack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FormAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String> genderList;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        genderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        genderList.add("Male");
        genderList.add("Female");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<String> getGenderList() {
        return genderList;
    }

    public void setGenderList(List<String> genderList) {
        this.genderList = genderList;
    }
}
```

This I have done I will be glad if it helps you.